# VBA to clear contents of cell if range is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that works pretty well except for a flaw. It checks for the text in a range and returns a text in the adjacent cell. I want it return a blank cell (**Column B**) if the adjacent range rows (**Column C to G**) are empty. This is the code below

```
Sub status_summary()
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim fail As Boolean
    Dim mrit As Boolean
    Dim pass As Boolean

    For r = 2 To 6
        If Range("C" & r) = "Failed" Then fail = True
        If Range("C" & r) = "Merit" Then mrit = True
        If Range("C" & r) = "Pass" Then pass = True

        If Range("D" & r) = "Failed" Then fail = True
        If Range("D" & r) = "Merit" Then mrit = True
        If Range("D" & r) = "Pass" Then pass = True

        If Range("E" & r) = "Failed" Then fail = True
        If Range("E" & r) = "Merit" Then mrit = True
        If Range("E" & r) = "Pass" Then pass = True

        If Range("F" & r) = "Failed" Then fail = True
        If Range("F" & r) = "Merit" Then mrit = True
        If Range("F" & r) = "Pass" Then pass = True

        If Range("G" & r) = "Failed" Then fail = True
        If Range("G" & r) = "Merit" Then mrit = True
        If Range("G" & r) = "Pass" Then pass = True

        If pass = True Then Range("B" & r) = "Pass"
        If mrit = True Then Range("B" & r) = "Merit"
        If fail = True Then Range("B" & r) = "Failed"

        fail = False
        mrit = False
        pass = False

    Next r

    MsgBox ("All Done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need such a big code or VBA for this :)

**NON VBA Method**

Using Formula

This goes in Cell `B2`. Simply copy it down.

`=IF(COUNTA(C2:G2)=0,"",IF(COUNTIF(C2:G2,"Failed")>0,"Failed",IF(COUNTIF(C2:G2,"Merit")>0,"Merit",IF(COUNTIF(C2:G2,"Pass")>0,"Pass",""))))`

[image]

However if you still want VBA then see the below.

**VBA METHOD**

**A)** Shortening your code

```
Sub status_summary()
    Dim r As Integer

    For r = 2 To 6
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C" & r & ":G" & r)) = 0 Then
            Range("B" & r) = ""
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C" & r & ":G" & r), "Failed") > 0 Then
            Range("B" & r) = "Failed"
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C" & r & ":G" & r), "Merit") > 0 Then
            Range("B" & r) = "Merit"
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C" & r & ":G" & r), "Pass") > 0 Then
            Range("B" & r) = "Pass"
        End If
    Next r

    MsgBox ("All Done")
End Sub
```

**B)** Using Formulas in VBA

```
Sub status_summary()
    Range("B2:B6").Formula = "=IF(COUNTA(C2:G2)=0,"""",IF(COUNTIF(C2:G2,""Failed"")>0,""Failed"",IF(COUNTIF(C2:G2,""Merit"")>0,""Merit"",IF(COUNTIF(C2:G2,""Pass"")>0,""Pass"",""""))))"

    MsgBox ("All Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddhart. I should make clear that in my criteria Failed>Merit>Pass. so if the range of cells is empty return empty in column B otherwise follow the criteria.

Comment: Check the updated post above. You will have to refresh the page.